# My kendo chart is not updating

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I Have kendo chart and tree-view in my application.I want to to change the value axis dynamically on check-box checked event,example When we check the "KM" check-box in treeview then value axis for Km  and data will be displaying in chart.

so I tried some code then my chart is not displaying.
My checked event code is

```
$("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");

    var checkedSeries = [];

    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function() {
        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

        $.each(valueAxes, function(index, valueAxes) {
            if (valueAxes.field == nodeText) {
                checkedSeries.push(valueAxes);
            }
        });
    });

    chart.options.valueAxes = checkedSeries;
    chart.refresh();
});
```

What's wrong in my code please help me.
Here is my jsbin http://jsbin.com/eyibar/11/edit

Comment: Hello I tried that one chart is displaying but value axis is not changed on click event here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/eyibar/12/edit

Answer (score 1):

First you need to assign the chart to a variable in on-change event event of tree view,without that the tree-view didn't recognize the chart and it's value axis and in your valueAxes code there is no property of field,so by name of the valueAxes you need to check the treeview node and then push the valueAxes.

```
$("#treview").on("change", function (e) {
                var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                var checkedSeries = [];
                if ($("#treeview").find(":checked").length !== 0) {
                    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function () {
                        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();
                        $.each(valueAxes, function (index, valueAxes) {
                            if (valueAxes.name == nodeText) {
                                checkedSeries.push(valueAxes);
                                checkedSeries.visible = true;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    createChart(checkedSeries);
                }
                else {
                    createChart(checkedSeries);
                }
            });
```